# Exception thrown while trying to access try-with-resouce resources in an anonymous inner class

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel, try-with-resources

Am working on a project where am populating a table with data from my database. am using try-with-resources statement because i want my `Connection` ,`Statement`, and `ResultSet` objects to be closed after leaving my `try-with-resources` statement.
 Inside my `try` block i have declared a `JTable` object which uses an anonymous inner class that populate the table with data from database.

**problem:** am getting `java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed` from any method in anonymous inner class that tries to access resouces inside the try-with-resources parenthesis.

**question:** what do i need to do or change so that my resources can be accessed by my anonymous inner class which is inside the `try-with-resources` statement

```
public class School extends JFrame{
private JTable mytable;
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/students";//am connecting to the students database
String username="";
String password="";
public School(){
   super("computer science students");

try(Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, username,password);
Statement smt=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet rst=smt.executeQuery("select * from students.studentstable")){

   final ResultSetMetaData metadata=rst.getMetaData();
   mytable=new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(){
     @Override
     public int getRowCount(){
       try{
         rst.last();
       return rst.getRow();
       }catch(SQLException sqlex){
          System.out.println(sqlex);
          return 0;
       }
     }
     @Override
     public int getColumnCount(){
         try{
         return metadata.getColumnCount();
         }catch(SQLException sqlex){
          System.out.println(sqlex);
          return 0;
       }
     }
     @Override
     public Class getColumnClass(int col){
        try{
            String classname=metadata.getColumnClassName(col+1);
           return Class.forName(classname);
        }catch(SQLException |ClassNotFoundException sqlex){
          System.out.println(sqlex.getMessage());
          return Object.class;
       }
     }
     @Override
     public String getColumnName(int col){
         try{
             String name=metadata.getColumnName(col+1);
             return name;
         }catch(SQLException sqlex){
          System.out.println(sqlex.getErrorCode());
          return "";
       }
     }

       @Override
     public Object getValueAt(int row,int col){
         try{
        rst.absolute(row+1);
        return rst.getObject(col+1);
         }catch(SQLException sqlex){
             System.out.println(sqlex.getErrorCode());
             return "";
         }
     }  
   });
   JScrollPane pane=new JScrollPane(mytable);
   add(pane);
}catch(SQLException sqlexc){
   System.out.println(sqlexc);
} 
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
  School frame=new School();
  frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Problem is, that your model's methods are executed (maybe long) after you left the try-with-resources block. Therefore your connection is already closed at that time, while the model object's methods are still referencing the ResultSet-Object of the closed connections (as it is implicitly final).

The current workflow is as follows:

1. the Connection is opend
2. the ResultSet object r is created
3. the anonymous model object m is created
4. the table t is created and references model m
5. the Connection and the ResultSet is closed
6. [maybe other operations]
7. the table t uses the model's methods to compute rowcount, values, ....

In step 7, the model's methods are trying to use the ResultSet object r to obtain informations. This causes your exceptions.

In order to get this to work you have to extract the necessary informations (rowcount, values) before the connection is closed and pass the result to the model's methods (mabye by using final objects) or reopen a connection within the model's methods when the informations is needed (lazy loading of the values).

Edit: tree -> table (name correct data structure)

Comment: what do you mean by "the tree t is created and references model m " in your answer? or did you mean table? onther thing you have said that Connection and ResultSet is closed (point 5 of your answer), resources are not closed before leaving the try statement/block! that means anything in the block should access those resources!

Comment: @gikarasojokinene Seems you have some strange view of the execution process there. The models methods aren't even called in the same thread, let alone inside the try-catch block. What you are creating is kind of a proxy, that, when asked for table data, refers to its saved reference of the ResultSet. It *does not* extend the try block indefinitely. And that asking happens *when the table is drawn*, not when it's created.

Comment: 2. the code of the anonymous inner class is written within the try-block but is not executed while the java programm runs within that try-block; at runtime, in the try block an anonymous class is created (with methods referencing the resultset), an object of that class is instancated and a table is created. The methods of that anonymous objects are called when the tree needs the information and thats after the connection is closed.

Comment: Maybe it helps for your imagination, when you try to refactor your anonymous class into a named class. Then you see you need to provide the ResultSet and the MetaData-object via constructor (the current version runs only because those objects are implicit final).

Comment: @flo so you mean the methods are declared at runtime and executed when execution reaches "frame.setVisible(true)" because the table will need data for it to be visible.   thats my understanding of this matter

Comment: They are defined at runtime within the try-block, but executed later, yes. ( I think the declaration itself is done during development time but I mix up those two terms constantly ;-) ). You can see the exact time of the execution in your exceptions stack trace.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that in order to access a field from an anonymous inner class, it must be declared as a final field.  Try taking your variables out of the resources block, declaring them final, and manually closing them at the end.

Comment: Did you just advise the OP to hog a DB connection for the entire lifetime of his app for the purposes of displaying a static table?...

Comment: @DHerls i know that method of explicitly closing my connections but that is what i want to avoid.